# Maybe Int to Int from findIndex with Strings

Tags: haskell

I've just started with Haskell and have to solve the following task.

I have a list which contains weekdays and I need the index corresponding to the location of the value `st` if it is found in the list:

```
weekdays = ["Montag","Dienstag","Mittwoch","Donnerstag","Freitag","Samstag","Sonntag"]

findIndex(==st)weekdays
```

My code works so far,  that i get `Just 3` for example. However, I read, that this is a `Maybe Int` and I need just the number out of it.

So, I added a function `eliminate`:

```
eliminate :: Maybe Int -> Int
eliminate (Just a) = a
```

But if I use `eliminate findIndex(==st)weekdays` it doesn't work and the error is:

```
*** Expression     : eliminate findIndex (flip (==) st) weekdays
*** Term           : eliminate
*** Type           : Maybe Int -> Int
*** Does not match : a -> b -> c -> d
```

And I can't figure out a way to go from here, since I'm a beginner.

Can someone help me out? The code has to work on Hugs98 unfortunately.

Comment: Beware your program will crash horribly as soon as you search for a misspelled day name.

Comment: its just a part of the code, i took care of that. But thanks for pointing it out =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the type error reported by Hugs relates to associativity and precedence of function application. Your expression

```
eliminate findIndex (== st) weekdays
```

attempts to apply `eliminate` to `findIndex` first, which is not the intent of your code. I think what you really want to do is:

```
eliminate (findIndex (== st) weekdays)
```

or

```
eliminate $ findIndex (== st) weekdays
```

These both apply `eliminate` to the result of `findIndex (== st) weekdays`. This should type-check as expected.

But, in answer to your question about how to deal with the `Maybe` value: you can use [`fromJust`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromJust) or [`fromMaybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-M) to extract the contained value.

The links go to the current GHC documents but there should be equivalent Hugs functions.

Here's a hint for future use: you can search the Haskell documentation online using [Hoogle](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-M). The best thing is that you can search both by function name and by type signature. For example, searching by [`Maybe a -> a`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Maybe+a+-%3E+a) would've found both these functions.

Another approach is to pattern-match on `Nothing` as well as `Just a`:

```
eliminate (Just a) = -- Handle a
eliminate Nothing = -- Handle error case
```

Of course, then you have to decide what `eliminate` should evaluate to in the error case.

Comment: @LoWesT: I've added more comments about the precedence of your original expression to explain the original compiler error you observed.